# How to extract certain blocks from xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog>
   <changeSet author="debdipta.h (generated)" id="1442927616936-399">
      <createTable tableName="SI_FORWARDING_EVENT_HISTORY_AU">
         <column name="FORWARDING_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="FORWARDING_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="COMMENTS_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
         <column name="COMMENTS_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
         <column name="XML_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
         <column name="XML_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
         <column name="CREATED_BY_O" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="CREATED_BY_N" type="NUMBER" />
         <column name="CREATION_DATE_O" type="date" />
         <column name="CREATION_DATE_N" type="date" />
         <column name="AUDIT_TRAIL_REASON" type="VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)" />
         <column name="TRANSACTION_TYPE" type="VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)" />
      </createTable>
   </changeSet>

   <changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
      <createView />
   </changeSet>

   <changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
      <createTable />
   </changeSet>

   <changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
      <createView />
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I want to extract the blocks only with createTable to be extracted to some other xml file using xpath. The result should look like:

```
<databaseChangeLog>
<changeSet author="debdipta.h (generated)" id="1442927616936-399">
        <createTable tableName="SI_FORWARDING_EVENT_HISTORY_AU">
            <column name="FORWARDING_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARDING_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="COMMENTS_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="COMMENTS_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="XML_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="XML_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="CREATED_BY_O" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="CREATED_BY_N" type="NUMBER"/>
            <column name="CREATION_DATE_O" type="date"/>
            <column name="CREATION_DATE_N" type="date"/>
            <column name="AUDIT_TRAIL_REASON" type="VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)"/>
            <column name="TRANSACTION_TYPE" type="VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)"/>
        </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
        <createTable></createTable>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The code I have done still now is as follows:

```
public class extractXML {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        //String test=readXMLasString.convert("E:\\db.borilog.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc=db.parse(new FileInputStream("E:\\db.borilog.xml"));
        XPath xpath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node res=(Node) xpath.evaluate("databaseChangeLog/changeSet",doc,XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(NodeToString(res));
    }

public static String NodeToString(Node node)throws TransformerException{
    StringWriter buf=new StringWriter();
    Transformer xform=TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    xform.transform(new DOMSource(node),new StreamResult(buf));
    return(buf.toString());


}
}
```

I am not undrstanding how to loop through the xpath and extract the required blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read XML using XPath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NodeList`:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//changeSet[createTable]",doc,XPathConstants.NODE);
String[] results = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(index);
    String nodeAsString = NodeToString(node);
    results[index] = nodeAsString;
}
```

Comment: Yeah finally resolved the problem. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That would return you blocks all createTable blocks.

```
//changeSet[createTable]
```

or

```
/databaseChangeLog/changeSet[createTable]
```

Here you ask to return changeSet blocks where createTable exists.

Result

```
<changeSet author="debdipta.h (generated)" id="1442927616936-399">
  <createTable tableName="SI_FORWARDING_EVENT_HISTORY_AU">
    <column name="FORWARDING_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="FORWARDING_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="ASSIGNMENT_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="ORIGINAL_USER_ID_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="FORWARD_FROM_USER_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="FORWARD_TO_USER_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="COMMENTS_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
    <column name="COMMENTS_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
    <column name="XML_O" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
    <column name="XML_N" type="VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" />
    <column name="CREATED_BY_O" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="CREATED_BY_N" type="NUMBER" />
    <column name="CREATION_DATE_O" type="date" />
    <column name="CREATION_DATE_N" type="date" />
    <column name="AUDIT_TRAIL_REASON" type="VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)" />
    <column name="TRANSACTION_TYPE" type="VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)" />
  </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="deb.h" id="4588999797">
  <createTable />
</changeSet>
```

Comment: It is returning only one  createTable block.

Comment: It is finding the first instance of the createTable it got.

Comment: it's because you have an issue in your XML. There are 2 closed changeSet in it goes one by one.

Comment: If you look more carefully on XML, you will figure out, that 2-nd changeSet is not closed properly. Right? It includes another changeSet.

Comment: Also try to test here, in case if it still does not work: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Thanks Dmytro for the help. The link you provided says its supposed to take all the createTable elements but the xpath is not taking that. It is only providing me with the first instance of createTable

Comment: can't help more than that. xpath is correct.
I suspect your XML structure is sightly different from what you posted. Try to get //changeSet - what does it return?

Comment: Things were correct. Instead of casting as a node I casted it as a nodelist. Now it  has solved my problem.